How do I specify that my assembly code runs on a specific core using MPIDR_EL1 in ARMv8 architecture
I'm trying to understand bare-metal startup code for Raspberry-pi 4.
In that code,
the first thing is to check if execution is done by core 0.
start:
    // Check processor ID is zero (executing on main core), else hang
    mrs     x1, mpidr_el1
    and     x1, x1, #3
    cbz     x1, 2f

I vaguely understand that the bits [1:0] of MPIDR distinguish cores 0-3 since raspi 4 has 4-cores of Cortex-A72, but I still haven't gained a detailed understanding of the MPIDR register.
I searched through manuals like the ARMv8 TRM, cortex-A72 TRM, and the internet too, but couldn't find a clear explanation of the MPIDR.
I'm particularly confused about the differences between aff0, aff1, and aff2, as well as the concept of cluster ID.
And, in cortex-a72 trm, It seems that the bits [1:0] of MPIDR can only represent four cores. If I have a processor like the Lx2160A with 16 cores, how can I determine which core I want to execute on?
Could you explain the concepts of aff0, aff1, and aff2 in the MPIDR, as well as the concept of cluster ID? Additionally, could you clarify how do I specify that my assembly code runs on a specific core?

Check the ARM Architecture Reference Manual, for ARMv8 Architecture.  There's a section on the MPIDR_EL1 register which gives a description of its fields.  There are way more than 4 bits for giving a CPU number.

I checked the document and the section on the MPIDR_EL1.. but I can’t get a sense about affinity level and cluster in context of multiprocessor.. Could you please let me know if there are explanations of affinity levels and clusters elsewhere in this document?

The idea is that in a NUMA system, you have different tiers of CPUs.  A system could have multiple boards, each of which has multiple sockets, each of which has multiple cores, each of which has multiple threads.  The different affinity levels reflect this possibility: if multithreading is used, the MT bit is set and Aff0 indicates which thread of one core we are.  Aff1 then indicates which core in one socket we are, Aff2 which socket on one board and Aff3 a possible affinity level above that.  If MT is not used, this is shifted down one level and Aff0 indicates the core of a socket.

On ARM systems, there may be a “cluster” affinity level between the core and the socket level for a total of 4 levels; what exactly these levels are can vary between systems, but with each level, communication between threads with different affinity on that level is expected to take longer than for threads with the same affinity on that level.

The RPi4 has 4 cores and is a true SMP system with no different affinities.  So only Aff0 is meaningful and the others are all 0.  Hence the boot code gets away with inspecting the least significant two bits of the mpidr_el1 register.

I've got it thanks to your answer! So, if you happen to know, could you kindly share an example of how MPIDR_EL1 is utilized with SoCs which have more than four cores like the LX2160A? Is the configuration of MPIDR_EL1 typically confidential in commercial SoCs? I couldn't find any description of the CPU cluster configuration for the LX2160A.

Sorry, I cannot give an example.  I don't think it's confidential, but there may not be explicit documentation.
